# iOS Take Screenshot on Curent Device Display not App Screen

Tags: c#, ios, swift, xamarin.ios

I have these codes (written in C#) to take a screenshot, but it only take the App Screen, even if I minimize my app, it still capture my App screen. I want to take the whole device screen, even I open another app, it will shows the screenshot of other app, desktops etc...

In C# Xamarin

```
var view = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.View;

UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(view.Frame.Size);
view.DrawViewHierarchy(view.Frame, true);
var image = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphics.EndImageContext();

using (var imageData = image.AsPNG())
{
    var bytes = new byte[imageData.Length];
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(imageData.Bytes, bytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(imageData.Length));
    return bytes;
}
```

You can post suggestion in Swift/Objective-C too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case , you should use the `View` of **UIScreen** instead of current **ViewController** .

```
CGSize size = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size;
nfloat scale = UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale;

UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(size,true,scale);
           UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.Layer.RenderInContext(UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext());

UIImage image = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphics.EndImageContext();
```

If you want to let the screen shot contains the status bar , you could refer the 
following  OC code

```
+ (UIImage *)screenshotWithStatusBar:(BOOL)withStatusBar rect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIInterfaceOrientation o = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    return [self screenshotWithStatusBar:withStatusBar rect:rect orientation:o];
}

+ (UIImage *)screenshotWithStatusBar:(BOOL)withStatusBar rect:(CGRect)rect orientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)o
{
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = CGRectGetWidth(screenRect);
    CGFloat screenHeight = CGRectGetHeight(screenRect);
    CGAffineTransform preTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    switch (o)
    {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
            //move screenshot rect origin to down left
            //rotate screenshot rect to meet portrait
            //move screenshot rect origin to up left
            //....yes, with a single line..
            preTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(preTransform, -rect.origin.x, -rect.origin.y);
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            //move screenshot rect origin to down left
            preTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(preTransform, screenWidth - rect.origin.x, -rect.origin.y);
            //rotate screenshot rect to meet portrait
            preTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(preTransform, M_PI);
            //move screenshot rect origin to up left
            preTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(preTransform, 0, -screenHeight);
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            //move screenshot rect origin to down left
            preTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(preTransform, -rect.origin.x, -rect.origin.y);
            //rotate screenshot rect to meet portrait
            preTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(preTransform, M_PI_2);
            //move screenshot rect origin to up left
            preTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(preTransform, 0, -screenHeight);
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            //move screenshot rect origin to down left
            preTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(preTransform, screenHeight - rect.origin.x, screenWidth - rect.origin.y);
            //rotate screenshot rect to meet portrait
            preTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(preTransform, - M_PI_2);
            //move screenshot rect origin to up left
            preTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(preTransform, 0, -screenHeight);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    // Create a graphics context with the target size
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 0);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    BOOL hasTakenStatusBarScreenshot = NO;
    // Iterate over every window from back to front
    for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows])
    {
        if (![window respondsToSelector:@selector(screen)] || [window screen] == [UIScreen mainScreen])
        {
            // -renderInContext: renders in the coordinate space of the layer,
            // so we must first apply the layer's geometry to the graphics context
            CGContextSaveGState(context);

            // Apply pre tranform to context.
            // to convert all interface orientation situation to portrait situation.
            CGContextConcatCTM(context, preTransform);
            // Center the context around the window's anchor point
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, [window center].x, [window center].y);
            // Apply the window's transform about the anchor point
            CGContextConcatCTM(context, [window transform]);
            // Offset by the portion of the bounds left of and above the anchor point
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context,
                                  -[window bounds].size.width * [[window layer] anchorPoint].x,
                                  -[window bounds].size.height * [[window layer] anchorPoint].y);


            // Render the layer hierarchy to the current context
            if ([window respondsToSelector:@selector(drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:)]) {
                [window drawViewHierarchyInRect:window.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
            } else {
                [window.layer renderInContext:context];
            }

            // Restore the context
            CGContextRestoreGState(context);
        }

        // Screenshot status bar if next window's window level > status bar window level
        NSArray *windows = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows];
        NSUInteger currentWindowIndex = [windows indexOfObject:window];
        if (windows.count > currentWindowIndex + 1)
        {
            UIWindow *nextWindow = [windows objectAtIndex:currentWindowIndex + 1];
            if (withStatusBar && nextWindow.windowLevel > UIWindowLevelStatusBar && !hasTakenStatusBarScreenshot)
            {
                [self mergeStatusBarToContext:context rect:rect screenshotOrientation:o];
                hasTakenStatusBarScreenshot = YES;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (withStatusBar && !hasTakenStatusBarScreenshot)
            {
                [self mergeStatusBarToContext:context rect:rect screenshotOrientation:o];
                hasTakenStatusBarScreenshot = YES;
            }
        }
    }

    // Retrieve the screenshot image
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}

+ (void)mergeStatusBarToContext:(CGContextRef)context
                           rect:(CGRect)rect
          screenshotOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)o
{
    UIView *statusBarView = [UIView statusBarInstance_ComOpenThreadOTScreenshotHelper];
    UIInterfaceOrientation statusBarOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    CGFloat screenWidth = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
    CGAffineTransform preTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    if (o == statusBarOrientation)
    {
        preTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(preTransform, -rect.origin.x, -rect.origin.y);
    }
    //Handle status bar orientation in portrait and portrait upside down screen shot
    else if((o == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait && statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) ||
            (o == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown && statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight))
    {
        preTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(preTransform, 0, rect.size.height);
        preTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(preTransform, - M_PI_2);
        preTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(preTransform, CGRectGetMaxY(rect) - screenHeight, -rect.origin.x);
    }
    else if((o == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait && statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) ||
            (o == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown && statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft))
    {
        preTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(preTransform, 0, rect.size.height);
        preTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(preTransform, M_PI_2);
        preTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(preTransform, -CGRectGetMaxY(rect), rect.origin.x - screenWidth);
    }
    else if((o == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait && statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) ||
            (o == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown && statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait))
    {
        preTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(preTransform, 0, rect.size.height);
        preTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(preTransform, - M_PI);
        preTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(preTransform, rect.origin.x - screenWidth, CGRectGetMaxY(rect) - screenHeight);
    }
    //Handle status bar orientation in landscape left and landscape right screen shot
    else if((o == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft && statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) ||
            (o == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight && statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown))
    {
        preTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(preTransform, 0, rect.size.height);
        preTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(preTransform, M_PI_2);
        preTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(preTransform, -CGRectGetMaxY(rect), rect.origin.x - screenHeight);
    }
    else if((o == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft && statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) ||
            (o == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight && statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft))
    {
        preTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(preTransform, 0, rect.size.height);
        preTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(preTransform, M_PI);
        preTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(preTransform, rect.origin.x - screenHeight, CGRectGetMaxY(rect) - screenWidth);
    }
    else if((o == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft && statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) ||
            (o == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight && statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait))
    {
        preTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(preTransform, 0, rect.size.height);
        preTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(preTransform, - M_PI_2);
        preTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(preTransform, CGRectGetMaxY(rect) - screenWidth, -rect.origin.x);
    }

    // -renderInContext: renders in the coordinate space of the layer,
    // so we must first apply the layer's geometry to the graphics context
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    // Apply pre transform
    CGContextConcatCTM(context, preTransform);
    // Center the context around the window's anchor point
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, [statusBarView center].x, [statusBarView center].y);
    // Apply the view transform about the anchor point
    CGContextConcatCTM(context, [statusBarView transform]);
    // Offset by the portion of the bounds left of and above the anchor point
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context,
                          -[statusBarView bounds].size.width * [[statusBarView layer] anchorPoint].x,
                          -[statusBarView bounds].size.height * [[statusBarView layer] anchorPoint].y);

    // Render the layer hierarchy to the current context
    if ([statusBarView respondsToSelector:@selector(drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:)]) {
        [statusBarView drawViewHierarchyInRect:statusBarView.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    } else {
        [statusBarView.layer renderInContext:context];
    }

    // Restore the context
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that is impossible. For security reasons, iOS doesn’t allow apps to take screenshots of anything but their own view hierarchy.

**Update:** To clarify, the only way to get screenshots of other apps in your application is to have the user take the screenshot manually (using the home + power button) and then have the user send/share it to your app (by [supporting and handling image file types](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html)), or have the user pick it from their photo library (using [UIImagePickerController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller)).

There's currently no option to fully automate this process.

Comment: But then how does there are plenty apps on Apple Store can do so. Even ReplayKit can record screen and streaming it./

Comment: Can you name examples of such apps? Even the ReplayKit recorder and broadcaster are limited to recording or broadcasting the views of the app it was started from. See the apple docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/replaykit/rpscreenrecorder "Your app can record the audio and video inside of the app".

Comment: A WWDC session from a few years ago seems to indicate that apps can stream content outside of their app using the live broadcast feature of ReplayKit 2: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/606/

Comment: @RyanPendleton To record your entire iOS screen (including all apps) using ReplayKit you have to start recording/streaming from the iOS control panel. You can send the video/stream data to an app to process it (using broadcast extensions), but the recoding/streaming itself can only be controlled from the iOS system interface. Recordings/streams started and controlled within an app can only record their apps view hierarchy.

Comment: It's the same with screenshots. You can take a screenshot of any app anywhere using the system buttons (home + power) and then later send/share the screenshot to an app. But apps cannot initiate or control taking the screenshots (unless it's of their own view hierarchy)